# Angular 5 Warning in Invalid selector ';

Tags: css, angular, typescript, css-selectors, styles

I have an angular 5 appplication. When I execute `ng b --prod` it shows me the following messages:

> Warning in Invalid selector ';
>   .space1x at 6219:39. Ignoring.

The style `space1x` in style.css is:

```
.space1x {
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

When I see in deployed css (styles.75b74.bundle.css), the style `space1x` is omitted.

What is happening in this case?

Comment: Can we see the whole style.css file?

Answer (score 1):

I was checking style.css and I finally solved it. I'll tell my way:

In some place of style.css contains the following instructions:

```
.pagination li.page-item a{color: #333};
.space1x {
    padding-left: 200px;
 }
```

In first line the semicolon is outside from right brace. So when I deploy by ng s --prod, angular omits space1x in style.css bundle. Therefore, the correct instruction should be like this:

```
.pagination li.page-item a{color: #333;}
```

By doing this, warning disappears and space1x is included in style.css bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 5 with SCSS, it was working and also this class available in bundle.css file, after the build.